# flip an ico-image without quality loss or size increase

Tags: icon, imagemagick, favicon

My goal is to take an ico-image, like this [wikipedia.ico](https://en.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico) and flip it vertically. My first attempt was

```
$ convert -flip wikipedia.ico flipped.ico
```

And it works, except that the resulting file `flipped.ico` is larger than the original:

```
$ identify wikipedia.ico 
wikipedia.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 4-bit sRGB 2734B 0.000u 0:00.000
wikipedia.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 4-bit sRGB 2734B 0.000u 0:00.000
wikipedia.ico[2] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 4-bit sRGB 2734B 0.000u 0:00.000

$ identify flipped.ico 
flipped.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 15086B 0.000u 0:00.000
flipped.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 15086B 0.000u 0:00.000
flipped.ico[2] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 8-bit sRGB 15086B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Adding the flag `-depth 4` does not help.

How can I do I get the exact same image, simply flipped?

*Edit*:

Thanks to Paolo Gibellini's answer, it got a smaller file `flipped.ico`. However, using  `-colors 16 -depth 4` still results in a file, that is much larger than the original:

```
$ convert -flip -colors 16 -depth 4 wikipedia.ico flipped.ico
$ ls -l flipped.ico wikipedia.ico
[...] 10734 May 14 21:05 flipped.ico
[...]  2734 May 14 09:41 wikipedia.ico
$ identify flipped.ico 
flipped.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 10734B 0.000u 0:00.009
flipped.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 4-bit sRGB 10734B 0.000u 0:00.000
flipped.ico[2] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 4-bit sRGB 10734B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I am running this on a debian pc. In the first line, there still seems to be some 8-bit image. Is there a way to have flipped.ico exactly the same size? Dos this really work on windows, as mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the flag `-depth 4` work, you should use also the flag **`-colors`** with the desired color depth (in your case 16).

The following command should generate an icon with the same size of the original:

```
$ convert -flip -colors 16 -depth 4 wikipedia.ico flipped.ico
```

I have tested it on **Windows** (*ImageMagick version 7.0.3-Q16*) and the flipped icon has the **same size** of the original.

See also this [forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21456).

*-- Update --*

I've tested the command above on a **Debian** machine (*ImageMagick version 6.3.7-Q16*) and on a **CentOS** machine (*ImageMagick version 6.7.8-9-Q16*), and in both cases I obtained an icon with the **same size** of the original (2734 bytes).

Just as reference, the output of different versions of *identify* is different.

**identify 6.3.7**

```
identify wikipedia.ico
wikipedia.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 2.66992kb
wikipedia.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 2.66992kb
wikipedia.ico[2] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 2.66992kb
```

**identify 6.7.8-9**

```
identify wikipedia.ico
wikipedia.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 4-bit DirectClass 2.73KB 0.000u 0:00.000
wikipedia.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 4-bit DirectClass 2.73KB 0.000u 0:00.000
wikipedia.ico[2] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 4-bit DirectClass 2.73KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**identify 7.0.3**

```
identify wikipedia.ico
wikipedia.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 4-bit sRGB 2.73KB 0.000u 0:00.000
wikipedia.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 4-bit sRGB 2.73KB 0.000u 0:00.000
wikipedia.ico[2] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 4-bit sRGB 2.73KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Are you using an updated version of ImageMagick?

Comment: thanks, that is already an improvement! On my debian box however, the size of `flipped.ico` is still much larger. I will edit the question..

Comment: This is odd. When is possible I will test on a Debian machine.

Comment: That would be great! Did the test lead to any conclusion?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: I had used version 6.9.9-39 Q16 in my question above. Now I have tried a different machine with version 6.9.7-4 Q16 and it worked flawlessly. Seems to be some sort of bug in my particular version. Also not that the flag `depth 4` isn't even necessary; `colors 16` is enough. Great answer! And thank you for trying on different machines to get me on the right track!